# How to combine two surveys and set appropriate parameters with svydesign

Tags: r, survey

I have two surveys, each using a stratified sampling approach, stratified by age group.

I would like to combine these two surveys and get overall results.

I've used this command to specify strata specific design but how can I add on another level of hierarchy to account for the fact that the data come from two different areas?

```
svydesign(ids = ~1 , strata = ~agegroup,  data = merged, fpc = ~fpc)
```

Would it then be appropriate to draw conclusions by each age group (after combining the two samples)?

Edit:

Sample data:

```
agegroup = c(1,1,1,1,1)
community = c(A, B, B, A, A)
fpc = c(1205, 1179, 1179, 1205, 1205)
sex = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Could you post a small example of your data? Maybe 5 rows from each of the two separate datasets with only the minimal columns needed to set up the survey.

Comment: so sorry for my slow response. I have added some sample data. Thank you!